# Is there a way to get a tweet's favorite count?

Tags: twitter

I couldn't find how to do this through the API documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, there's no official way to get this at the present time. All you can tell is if the tweet has been favorited by the authenticated user.  There is a `favorites_count` in the object graph, however this applies to the user that tweeted the tweet, not the tweet itself.

*EDIT: Jun. 19, '12* - See mmrobins's answer for links to some of Twitter's undocumented API methods. As always, be careful when using undocumented endpoints since they can change without notice.

Answer (score 7):

There is an [undocumented way](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2012/01/twitter-unofficial-api-getting-tweets.html) to get this information if you're authenticated.

```
https://api.twitter.com/i/statuses/[tweet.id]/activity/summary.json
```

An even larger list of API endpoints that are undocumented can be found in the Ruby Twitter library https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/client.rb

Comment: The link is broken :( New link is https://github.com/sferik/twitter/tree/master/lib/twitter

Comment: According to comments in this blogpost http://blog.fgribreau.com/2012/01/twitter-unofficial-api-getting-tweets.html this method is no longer supported

Answer (score 6):

The New API V1.1 Now supports the tweet favorite's count. Here try it out

```
stdClass Object
        (
            [created_at] => Thu Apr 04 20:09:16 +0000 2013
            [id] => 319904523520983041
            [id_str] => 319904523520983041
            [text] => North Koreas perspective of the world in the next 5 years http://t.co/MxRgD00VCY
            [source] => web
            [truncated] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
            [geo] => 
            [coordinates] => 
            [place] => 
            [contributors] => 
            [retweet_count] => 7
            [favorite_count] => 7
            [entities] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [hashtags] => Array
```

Upgrade and start Using it.

Answer (score 5):

It is now possible to do this via the [statuses/show/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3aid) endpoint. (It requires authentication.)

Example:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=210462857140252672
```

or

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/210462857140252672.json
```

The returned JSON will have a favorite count member.

<s>Note that while the example response in the linked documentation says `"favourites_count"`, the actual returned JSON property is called `"favorite_count"`.</s>

**Edit:** I've just noticed that the documented `"favourites_count"` property is inside the `user` member of the response (it tells you how many tweets have the user favorited in total). The `"favorite_count"` property, which tells you how many times the tweet was favorited, is in the root of the returned JSON object, and it seems like it's undocumented.

(This endpoint also returns `retweet_count` and much more.)

Answer (score 0):

The official answer to your question is here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6898.
It suggests to count them real time as the functionality is not supported

Answer (score 0):

As workaround we can scrap page with tweet https://twitter.com/USERNAME/status/TWEET_ID

and use this regex to extract favorited count

```
(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=</strong> Favorites|$)
```

or use deprecated api

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/308910231910490112.json
```

Answer (score 0):

[official doc says](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6898)

> How do I count favorites?
>
> The number of times a tweet was favorited is now available as part of
>   tweet objects in the REST, Streaming, and Search APIs -- you'll find
>   it presented in the "favorite_count" field.
>
> Additionally, User streams and Site streams both stream events when an
>   authenticated user favorites tweets or has their tweets favorited.
>   Using these authenticated streaming APIs, you can count favorites in
>   real-time as they happen.

**But please note, that**

> **Site Streams is currently in a limited beta. Access is restricted to whitelisted accounts.**

And sorry for emotions, but it's in beta more than two years.

So you cannot..

[image: so you cannot just start and get favorites count]